# Javascript command to get an element's font color using XPATH

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, automation, robotframework

I'm trying to find the font color of an element through RobotFramework, but the Get Element Attribute keeps returning null. I decided to execute a JS expression instead, but can't find any online. The element doesn't have an ID so I need to use Xpath but all the resources I find is assuming it has an ID and to just use getElementByID, which won't work here.

HTML:

```
<p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; word-break: break-word;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px;">Some Text</p>
```

Xpath for the element:

```
//div[contains(@class,'ParentClass')]//p
```

In the console I tried this:

```
$x(".//div[contains(@class,'ParentClass')]//p").style.color
```

But it keeps returning undefined.

Comment: Get the element, then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Can you  show us the actual XPath expression you used ('ParentClass' looks a bit generic). You might find it more straightforward to use plain JS and HTML to get the element then use getComputedStyle as @Keith suggests.

Comment: I tried executing window.getComputedStyle($x(".//div[contains(@class,'StageModuleText_wrapper')]//p"), "font-color")


but getting the error 'Parameter 1 is not of type Element"

@Haworth, that's the full xpath I used

Comment: Pleas show the complete html